# How to add an angular workspace into npm workspace?

Tags: angular, npm, npm-workspaces

I have an existing npm workspace that contains two workspaces. Now I want to add another workspace to the existing workspace, and this new workspace is itself an Angular workspace with two applications.
I created a new folder in my npm workspace and then into it, I created an angular workspace. then in angular workspace folder's I generated two application.

I've tried adding the Angular workspace to the existing npm workspace, but I'm having trouble with properly integrating it and making sure that the two applications within the Angular workspace are accessible.

Can someone help me understand how to add an Angular workspace, which contains multiple applications, to an existing npm workspace?

npm workspace should be look like this:

```
.
├── workspace1
└── workspace2
└── angular-workspace
    ├── app-a
    │   
    └── app-b
```

Comment: Did you solved this issue? Did you found a solution?
I have the same exact problem and I don't understand how to create a new angular app inside an existing npm workspaces monorepo.

I didn't think it was so complex.